# Redirect serial port output to a socket

Tags: java, serial-port, byte

I have written a small program in Java which reads info from a serial port (some text messages and also some binary data, mixed), and then send it through a TCP socket.

At first I tried to get data into a buffer, and send everything when a '/n' arrived, but binary data doesn't work that way.

My second thought was sending the data all the time, byte by byte. But it gets too slow, and I guess I'm losing data while sending it, even thought I used threads.

Next idea would be sending data when I reach 100 bytes stored for example, but it is a dirty fix.

My serial data comes from a GPS receiver, and these devices usually send many sentences of data (text and binary) each second (or configurable to 10, 50, 100Hz, it depends of the model). Anyway, there is a gap of time where data is received, and a considerable larger gap of time when nothing is being received. I guess the fanciest way to get rid of my data would be detecting that gap and sending all the stored data then, before new data arrives when the gap ends.

How could I detect this kind of event?

EDIT: I use RXTX package to get rid of the serial port, and I'm working over Windows 7 64bits

Comment: What package do you use to access serial port? On which platform?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Just edited with that info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detegt the gap, just enable timeout with enableReceiveTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Just read and write byte[] buffers as you get them, making sure to only write the actual count returned by the read() method.